# Check specific value of a parameter , if it wont match then change it

Tags: linux, awk, sed

The output of the command displays 30.

```
bash-4.2$ sudo useradd -D | grep INACTIVE
INACTIVE=30
```

I need to change it to 35 . I need to check if the output of previous command is non-'35' value and if it is then it must change to 35.

```
bash-4.2$ sudo useradd -D -f 35
```

(If it` s a value other than 35 then the command useradd-D -f 35 should run.)

Answer (score 2):

If `sudo useradd -D` does not output `INACTIVE=35`, execute `sudo useradd -D -f 35`:

```
sudo useradd -D | grep 'INACTIVE=35' || sudo useradd -D -f 35
```